# Binary Search with 2 Elements

Tags: java, binary-search

I'm using binary search to find an object in array.
It works. but, if the array only has 2 objects, and the one I want to find is in the 2nd index, I'm getting -1.

```
mid = (low + high) / 2;
```

mid is getting 0, and then if songName isn't there it's returning -1

```
public int isSongExist(String songName) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = this.songs.length - 1;
    int mid;

    while (low <= high) {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;

        if (this.songs[mid].getSongName().compareToIgnoreCase(songName) < 0) {
            low = mid + 1;
        } else if (songs[mid].getSongName().compareToIgnoreCase(songName) > 0) {
            high = mid - 1;
        } else {
            return mid;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any debugging performed on this code.  Please [edit] your question to show us what your debugging has uncovered, as well as a specific question about a specific line of code.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Can't you use one of the Arrays.binarySearch() methods?
 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch-T:A-T-java.util.Comparator-

Comment: How are you storing the songnames in the array? In decreasing order of their lengths?

Comment: No, I can't use Arrays class. The songs are sorted by their names, like a phone numbers book.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is not in the code you posted. Here is a cut-down version of it that demonstrates it's correctness.

```
public int find(int[] a, int f) {
    int low = 0;
    int high = a.length - 1;
    int mid;

    while (low <= high) {
        mid = (low + high) / 2;

        if (a[mid] < f) {
            low = mid + 1;
        } else if (a[mid] > f) {
            high = mid - 1;
        } else {
            return mid;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

public void test(String[] args) {

    int[][] tests = {{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2}, {1}, {}};
    for (int[] t : tests) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(t));
        System.out.println("1 --> " + find(t, 1));
        System.out.println("2 --> " + find(t, 2));
        System.out.println("3 --> " + find(t, 3));
    }
}
```

It is therefore likely that either your songs list is incorrectly sorted or something else is wrong. I would suggest you use a debug tool to confirm your assumptions.

Comment: Try to find 1 in [2, 1], it'll return -1 instead of 1